# I have a error with my txt file and the FileInputStream

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I have the following code that returns a linked list with information from a txt. The problem is that I get the following error:

"File not found. MSJ:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D: \ Desktop \ game.txt (The file name, directory name, or syntax of the volume label are not correct)".

The path of my file is correct my txt is with UTF-8 and the syntax looks like this:

```
  ID Game: 0
  ID Stadium: 1
  ID Team 1: 102
  ID Team 2: 110
  Date Game: 2011-12-03
  --------------------------------------------
  ID Game: 1
  ID Stadium: 1
  ID Team 1: 102
  ID Team 2: 110
  Date Game: 2011-12-03
  --------------------------------------------
  ID Game: 2
  ID Stadium: 1
  ID Team 1: 102
  ID Team 2: 110
  Date Game: 2011-12-03
  --------------------------------------------
```

The code I'm using is this:

```
    public class ReadInfo_Carlos {

    private static LL_Games_Carlos llg;

    public static LL_Games_Carlos getGames(String filePath)
    {

    FileInputStream inputStream = null;

    Scanner sc = null;

    String sep="--------------------------------------------";

    try {


        inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);

        sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");

        String line = sc.nextLine();

        String[] s = null;

        String idG=null, idS=null, idTeam1=null, idTeam2=null, date=null;

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){

            while(!line.equals(sep)){

                s = line.split("ID Game: ");

                if(s.length>1) idG = s[1];

                line = sc.nextLine();


                s = line.split("ID Stadium: ");

                if(s.length>1) idS = s[1];

                line = sc.nextLine();


                s = line.split("ID Team 1: ");

                if(s.length>1) idTeam1 = s[1];

                line = sc.nextLine();


                s = line.split("ID Team 2: ");

                if(s.length>1) idTeam2 = s[1];

                line = sc.nextLine();


                s = line.split("Date Game: ");

                if(s.length>1) date = s[1];

                line = sc.nextLine();

            }

            if(sc.hasNextLine())

                line = sc.nextLine();

            llg.Insert(Integer.parseInt(idG), Integer.parseInt(idS), Integer.parseInt(idTeam1), Integer.parseInt(idTeam2), LocalDate.parse(date));

        }



    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

        System.out.println("File not found. MSJ: \n"+ex);

    } finally {

        if (inputStream != null) {

            try {

                inputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                System.out.println("IO Exception. MSJ: \n"+ex);

            }

        }

        if (sc != null) {

            sc.close();
        }
    }
    return llg;
  }



 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    String filePath = "‪‪D:\\Desktop\\game.txt";
    ReadInfo_Carlos.getGames(filePath);
 }
```

Comment: The error you mention `D: \ Downloads \ ga.txt` has spaces, while the code `"‪‪D:\\Downloads\\ga.txt"` does not. You should copy/paste _exactly_ the error message, and generally set it apart with back-ticks or indent it as a code block so it perfectly displays what you're seeing. Unrelated: you can use forward slashes `"D:/Downloads/ga.txt"` in Java, even on Windows, so you don't have to escape the backslashes.

Comment: `"\\"` in Java is just one \, as the first one is an escape character. You probably want to change them into `"‪‪/Downloads/ga.txt"` or something

Comment: I tried with a single slash and inverted slash but I still get the same error. I can not think what it could be. It can be a problem with the LocalDate or the syntax of my txt.